# Special SQLite sort order Swift 3

Tags: sqlite, uitableview, swift3

I want to have a sorted array of common names.  They would be easily sorted in SQLite by

```
`...ORDER BY RL_Species.species ASC`
```

However, not every species has a common name, so there are many records with "no common names".  I would like to sort all common names ASC, but have all of the "no common name" be on the bottom of the sorted list.

It is called in a TableViewController with the basic code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell       = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Resource.SpeciesCell)!

    let specieCommonName: UILabel   =         
            speciesCommonName.text   = self.species[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].commonName


    return cell
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: put you Query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below query :

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLENAME` ORDER BY case when RL_Species.species='no common name' then 1 else 0 end,RL_Species.species ASC
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.  Still sorts without error, but did not move "No Common Name" to end.

Comment: I missed that I typed "n" in "no common name". Changed it to "No" and It now works.  Thank you. This was great help